# How to set minDate is tomorrow in air datepicker plugin?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I need help. I have to set minDate is tomorrow date. i tried like this, but it isn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDiv').datepicker({
        minDate: "+1"
    });
});
```

I use [this plugin](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/). I saw examples, but there is only today's date. Thanks

Comment: best longtime approach for you will be to use **moment.js** javascript library for all datetime related calculations. You simple create a date variable and then using moment.js calculate one day less and then add that date to datepicker constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> To limit date selection, use `minDate` and `maxDate`, they must receive JavaScript Date object.

So you need to construct a date object first, and then increment the day field, then pass it to the `minDate` key.

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);

$('#myDiv').datepicker({
  minDate: minDate
});
```

Comment: yeahh. You're my savior)

Comment: great :), pls confirm this as your final ans

Answer (score 0):

try this , works with me using jquery datepicker

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDiv').datepicker({
        minDate: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: still not working. I caught this console error Uncaught TypeError: e.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: can u tell, which version are you using

Comment: I don't know. There is no info about version